# Set HTML input value using Kinetic.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs

I want to set the value of an HTML input box when the user clicks, usign Kinetic.js.

This is the input box:

```
<input type="text" id="text_box">
```

and this is the method

```
stage.on('mousedown touchstart', function(evt) {
var shape = evt.targetNode;
if (shape) {
  if (shape.getFill() == 'green') { 
    // this is where the text box value should be changed.
    // I tried this:
    $("#text_box").val("hello");
  }     
}
  });
```

It doesn't seem to work.

How can I do this?

Comment: try alerting instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should target the text box in your DOM.

```
document.getElementById("text_box").setAttribute("value","hello");
```

or

```
document.getElementById("text_box").value = "hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to bind your listener on the shape itself rather than the stage.

For instance:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var shape = new Kinetic.Circle({ /*... */ });

shape.on('mousedown touchstart', function(e){
  var that = e.targetNode;
  // ..
});

layer.add(shape);
```

Check out [this example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-multi-event-binding/).